# Which collection can be used to map key-value-pairs in both directions?

Tags: typescript, collections, key-value

I'm trying to setup a collection of country codes. Since my frontend displays it, I want to show "Austria" for example, but when sending it to the backend I just want to send "A", since that's how it is stored. Ideally it would look something like this:

```
CountryCodes = {
  A: "Austria",
  D: "Germany",
}

console.log(CountryCodes["A"]); // -> "Austria"
console.log(CountryCodes["Austria"]); // -> "A"
```

I thought I could use an enum since

```
enum MyEnum {
  first = 0,
  second = 1,
}
```

becomes

```
MyEnum = {
  0 = "first",
  1 = "second"
  first = 0,
  second = 1,
}
```

when being transpiled from typescript to javascript. But thats not the case if the values of the enums are not numbers.

I'm not sure what kind of collection to use, since I don't want to add two keyValuePairs for each countrycode. Do you have an idea how to solve a problem like this? Am I missing a very obvious solution here?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different approach. You can create your enums as string enums:

```
export enum MyEnum {
    A = "Australia",
    D = "Germany"
}
```

So when you render `<>MyEnum.A</>` Australia will be rendered.

You can then install [enum-values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enum-values) and simply do something like:

```
const val = EnumValues.getNameFromValue(MyEnum, 'Australia')
```

So that `val = A` and you can then send it to your backend.

Hope this helps.